# strange error "(22 - 'Invalid argument')" when used with IPv4

Tags: nmap

I have "(22 - 'Invalid argument')" using nmap.
I'V google'd and got https://seclists.org/nmap-dev/
but on that is it talks about IPv6 while I got this error using
IPv4 in no place IPv4 is mensionned, so why am I getting
this weird error ?

I entered

```
nmap --send-eth --release-memory --nsock-engine=epoll --allports --fuzzy 
--randomize-hosts --log-errors  --max-os-tries=9 -n --reason --append-output 
--scanflags=URGACKPSHRSTSYNFIN --max-retries=6 --host-timeout=225s
 --stats-every=10m --ttl=255 --min-hostgroup=5 --max-hostgroup=25 
--max-rtt-timeout=60s --scan-delay=250ms --max-scan-delay=25s 
--stats-every=1 -v5 -sT -sV -A -p 80-82 0.18.0.0
```

And got:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-17 16:05 CET
NSE: Loaded 148 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 16:05
Scanning 0.18.0.0 [2 ports]
Stats: 0:00:01 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (0 up), 1 undergoing Ping Scan
Ping Scan Timing: About 0.00% done
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Completed Ping Scan at 16:05, 0.50s elapsed (1 total hosts)
NSE: Script Post-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:05
Completed NSE at 16:05, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.46 seconds
```

When trying with less arguements `nmap -p 80-82 0.18.0.0`
got:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-17 16:24 CET
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Strange read error from 0.18.0.0 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

When trying with ncat I got:

```
marc@platinum:~/NCat_test$ nc -vvv 0.18.0.0 80
0.18.0.0: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [0.18.0.0] 80 (http) : Invalid argument
 sent 0, rcvd 0

marc@platinum:~/NCat_test$ nc -vvv 0.18.0.0 81
0.18.0.0: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [0.18.0.0] 81 (hosts2-ns) : Invalid argument
 sent 0, rcvd 0
```

I still have "Invalid argument" but this time instead of 22 I got the post numbers and service

80 (http)
81 (hosts2-ns)

This raises a few questions

1) does the "Invalid argument" of ncat and nmap relate to the same thing ?

2) how can I make nmap for informative instead of printing 22 ?

3) how can I say that the remote port is really CLOSEd or is it really OPENned and rejecting because of the firewall ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you format your code (including terminal input/output. You can use ``` (backticks) or indent longer snippets by 4 spaces for readablity.

Comment: Thank's for your reply.
This was really helpfull but also a bit confusing.

I'v read RFCs 1918 and 6890 and the following CIDR IPs are listed as unreachable

10.0.0.0/8
100.64.0.0/10
127.0.0.0/8
169.254.0.0/16
172.16.0.0/12
192.0.0.0/24
192.0.2.0/24
192.88.99.0/24
192.168.0.0/16
198.18.0.0/15
198.51.100.0/24
203.0.113.0/24
240.0.0.0/4
255.255.255.255/32

I'v tried to connect using nmap/ncat and succeeded on some of those

which I consider as an error since that are supposed to be 'unreachable'

thank's

Comment: reachable 'unreachable' IPs

127.254.254.254
169.254.0.1
192.0.3.1
127.158.154.70
127.122.122.10
127.36.6.123
127.66.103.130
127.12.163.165

conclusions for tests were all wrong because those IPs aren't supposed to be
This means:

1) RFCs are wrong : very unlikely
2) I'v misinterpreted the real meaning for those, that is I'v included IP ranges that are valid WITHIN the invalid IPs
3) those RFC were superseeded (invalidated by newer RFCs): April 2013 RFC6890, February 1996 RFC1918, as they are 5 and 22 yo resp.
4) the remote IPs sysadmins didn't follow RFCs

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The IP addresses in the `0.0.0.0/8` network (anything with `0` in the first position) are reserved to mean "Current network" and are only valid as source addresses. Nmap generally prefers to not disallow unusual things like invalid addresses or port numbers (port 0 is similarly reserved in most implementations), because interesting things happen when you disobey conventions. But when Nmap makes calls to your system's networking functions, they may produce errors like this.